# Using RegEx and Beautiful Soup to find anchor text - RegEx not working as expected

Tags: regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use Beautiful Soup to search the links of a page for keywords in the text using RegEx.

```
<a href="/company/05835190" onclick="javascript:_paq.push(['trackEvent', 'SearchSuggestions', 'SearchResult-1' ]);" title="View company"><strong>FOO</strong>blah blah<strong>BAR</strong>example</a>
```

Here is my simple code:

```
raw_html = simple_get(searchString) 
searchString = ...see below...

if len(str(raw_html)) != 0:
    html = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'html.parser')
    companyLink = html.find_all('a', string=re.compile(searchString, 
    re.IGNORECASE))
    print(companyLink)
```

Let's say that the link text is: Foo blah blah bar:

1. If searchString = "Foo" ->  match
2. If searchString = "Bar" ->  match
3. If searchString = "Foo(.)*Bar" -> NO MATCH
4. If searchString = "Foo blah blah bar" -> NO MATCH! 
   (I even copied the text directly from the web page)

I've tried companyLink = html.find_all('a', text=re.compile(searchString, re.IGNORECASE)) - no go

I've tried companyLink = html.find_all(string=re.compile(searchString, re.IGNORECASE)) - no go

I've tried companyLink = html.find_all(text=re.compile(searchString, re.IGNORECASE)) - no go

I think that all four versions of searchString should return a match. I really want to use version 3, since I know "Foo" and "Bar", and am not sure of what might be placed between.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong???

Comment: Try searching in `text` rather than `string`.

Comment: I've tried companyLink = html.find_all('a', text=re.compile(searchString, re.IGNORECASE)) - no go<br>
I've tried companyLink = html.find_all(string=re.compile(searchString, re.IGNORECASE)) - no go<br>
I've tried companyLink = html.find_all(text=re.compile(searchString, re.IGNORECASE)) - no go

Comment: Please share a part of the HTML document with the relevant tags.

Comment: Please add that HTML if you need an answer.

Comment: HTML added Wiktor

Comment: There are tags in between, so, the `string` is empty, and `text` will contain `'FOOblah blahBARexample'` (no spaces).

Comment: So, what solution do you need?

Answer (score 0):

OK - here's how I solved it - thanks to @Wiktor Stribiżew for helping to crack the code:

`<a href="/company/05835190" onclick="javascript:_paq.push(['trackEvent', 'SearchSuggestions', 'SearchResult-1' ]);" title="View company"><strong>FOO</strong>blah blah<strong>BAR</strong>example</a>`

```
companyName = 'Foo Bar'
searchTarget = re.compile(companyName, re.IGNORECASE)
raw_html = simple_get(searchString)

if len(str(raw_html)) != 0:
#run BeautifulSoup on the page HTML
   html = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'html.parser')
#find all links where title='View company'
   anchorTitle = html.find_all('a', title='View company')
#convert to string, remove <strong> tags
   a_tag = str(anchorTitle).replace('<strong>', '')
#remove </strong> tags
   a_tag = a_tag.replace('</strong>', '')
#remove multiple spaces
   a_tag = re.sub('( ){2,}',' ', a_tag)
#run BeautifulSoup again on the edited string
   b_tag = BeautifulSoup(a_tag, 'html.parser')
#find link where string = 'Foo Bar'
   anchorText = b_tag.find('a', string=searchTarget)

   print(anchorText)
```